# Issues with JavaScript Calculation

Tags: javascript

Trying to do a simple JavaScript calculation

```
var money = $("#money").val();
var percentRate =  "{{ $money->percent }}"/100;
var incomeMoney =  money * percentRate;
```

If the $amount->percent is a whole number it will give a correct figure but if I use a decimal point it won't.
Eg if I assign **23** to **$money->percent** it will give me the correct figure but if I assign decimal like **23.5** it will give a wrong figure.
I believe the system is rounding the **percentRate** to **0.23** instead of **0.235**. How do I get around this, Please?

Full code -
...

Comment: if i put `1 *  (23.5 / 100)` in my browser console it outputs `0.235`. witch you stated is the desired output. so the problem must lie elsewhere, please post some more context.

Comment: I have added the full code.
Thanks.

Comment: What is whole number?

Comment: "23.5"/100
0.235
check value of this "{{ $money->percent }}", no other way I see for you to get rounded answer

Comment: @IvanCherviakov Whole number = integer, decimal = float.

Thanks, guys, I have solved it.
The data is stored as a string and was parsed as an integer with parseInt instead of Float (parseFloat) so the parseInt function stripped the float value and was calculated as integer instead of float.